# Updates on Ubuntu after changing Desktop Environment

Tags: updates, desktop-environments

I am planning to switch my desktop environment and I just use it as it is, no other software is installed. But now I want to change to a different desktop enviroment, and my question is: will I still get updates or will it be rooting an android phone I will not get any updates. Also will I be able to keep the applications like Firefox and libre office to my new desktop (lxde).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please first register your account and then use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged.  In that way, you can then accept the answer that has helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Changing your desktop system does not prevent your computer from getting updates.

You may no longer see notifications about updates, as they are targeted at displaying on the default desktop system.  You also may find it harder to run graphical programs to perform updates, as they are built for Gnome.

You can always use the command line to do updates:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: `dist-upgrade` only upgrades packages that either have new dependencies or will remove another package.  For most updates `sudo apt-get update && sudo  apt-get upgrade` will do.

Comment: Seth: correct.  I updated the answer to include your better command.

Comment: "You may no longer see notifications about updates" can be avoided if OP just **adds** a new desktop. This way, all "desktops" will receive updates. Then, login time will provide the option to choose. Anyway, the question doesn't make clear whether OP wishes to remove the unnamed desktop and replace it with another desktop (lxde). Also, the reason for wanting to switch isn't mentioned :)

Comment: @Seth, I've switched from `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` a couple of months ago. I'm not seeing any downside (yet).

Comment: @vasa1  Using `dist-upgrade` as your main way of getting updates is not recommended because it will not double check with you if updating one package will remove another.  If you don't pay enough attention packages/dependencies could go missing or break.